# What is the difference in these two types of operator overloads?

Tags: c++

I have been looking at some open source code and I see two different definitions of overloading an operator. What is the difference between them and are there any benefits of doing either?

For example, one example we have a class:

```
class foo{
public:
    void SetValue(double input_value) {foo_value = input_value};
    double GetValue() {return foo_value;}
private:
    double foo_value;
};
```

Then I sometimes see two different types / styles of overloading the addition operator (for example)

```
class foo{
    const foo operator+(const foo& input_foo);
};

const foo foo::operator+(const foo& input_foo) {
    foo_value += input_foo.foo_value;
    return *this;
}
```

The other type of overload I sometimes see is:

```
class foo{
    friend const foo operator+(const foo& input_foo1, const foo& input_foo2);
};

const foo operator+(const foo& input_foo1, const foo& input_foo2); // Defined right after class

const foo operator+(const foo& input_foo1, const foo& input_foo2) {
    foo temp_foo;
    temp_foo.SetValue(input_foo1.GetValue() + input_foo2.GetValue());
    return temp_foo;
}
```

Comment: Your first version of `operator+` is completely wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Comment: You typically define them as outside-of-class methods with two arguments. On one hand that indicates they're not a fundamental part of that class but only use its public API, and on the other hand it also works if the left-hand side is not your class (but for example, an int).

Comment: @T.C. It would be helpful if you also provide the problem with first version.

Comment: @ravi The problem is the member function should be defined as const and not modify the object in question (as implemented it's more like operator +=).  Define it as `const foo operator+(const foo& input_foo) const;` and use the same implementation as the free function.

Comment: @dascandy So would you say it would be beneficial to use the second type if wanting to +- ints or doubles as well. And use first type if only doing foo +- foo?

Comment: @user2840470 Yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One overload is member function whereas other is free function.

You use free function so as to provide mixed-mode arithmetic. For e.g:-

```
foo f;
2 + f;    __1
```

__1 would compile only if there is free function `operator+`. Member function `operator+` won't do anything in this case.

Comment: @Rinzler A non-member function.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Why inventing new names, if the real name is `friend function`, no?

Comment: @Rinzler You don't want to make it friend if it can be implemented completely in terms of class public interface...

Comment: @Rinzler A friend function isn't necessarily a non-member function (that is, it can be a member function). And a non-member function doesn't equate to friend function.

Comment: @Rinzler: It's not a new name. The term has been around for quite some time.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Who said that (the opposite of what you said), me?

Comment: @Rinzler That's what I was picking up.

Comment: @ravi that makes sense, so if I am only doing foo +- foo, I should probably just the first type of definition? But if I want to do int +- foo or foo +- int, I would have to use the second type?

Comment: @user2840470 Only to support int + foo,  second version is justified. foo + int can be done using first version also. Remember you have to provide single argument non-explicit constructor in either of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

By an external point of view, `foo::operator+(const foo&)` and `::operaor+(const foo&, const foo&)` plays exactly the same role in making meaningful the `+` symbol when placed between two `foo`-s.   In particular the first is like the second when its own fisrt argument is `*this`.

By an internal point of view, they can have different capabilities in respect to the `foo` class:  `::operaor+(const foo&, const foo&)` is a "free function" (a function declared at global level): it has the beauty of the symmetry in treating the arguments in the same way, but cannot access foo's private data member, unless foo itself doesn't recognize it as its own `firend`.

`foo::operator+(const foo&)`, as a member function, can have free access to all foo members and data but -as a member of foo- is less suitable to "generic algorithms" (that may prefer a functional form).

There are also some other difference about possible variants: consider

```
foo a;
foo b;
int k;
```

Both the `operator+` seen above can give meaning to `a+b`, but what about `a+k` and `k+a`?

For `a+k` you can have either `foo::operator+(int)` or `::operator+(const foo&, int)`, but for k+a, you need `::operator+(int, const foo&)` since there is no way to have `+` as a meber of `int`.

All that said, you declaration and implementation look "fuzzy" (or at least incoherent):

```
const foo foo::operator+(const foo& input_foo) {
    foo_value += input_foo.foo_value;
    return *this;
}
```

When you write `c = a+b` do you expect the value of `a` to change?

What you do, here, is adding `b` to `a` and create a copy of `a` (why const? it's a copy after all, and you already changed `a`) you assign then to `c`.

Operator + should create a new object whose value is the sum

foo foo::operator+(const foo& rop) const // NOTE THE SIGNATURE, make it coherent with the decalration
{
   foo tmp;
   tmp.foo_value = foo_value + rop.foo_value;
   return tmp;
}

It's not the return type, but the member-function itself to be `const`, as the parameter if given by reference, so that you ensure that in `a+b` neither `a` or `b` is changed. The return type is just a plain value you can let your caller to treat as it wants, since it is returned into his own stack-frame.